# how to access HR Schema by Adf Mobile

Tags: oracle-adf-mobile, oracle-maf

I can't Access HR Schema Using ADF Mobile Is There more ways for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not possible to make **direct** database connection in ADF Mobile or MAF (Mobile Application Framework).
You will have to expose your data in a web service and consume it in your mobile app.